# Use Local Eclipse IDE Debugger with Remote Project Source (Linux)

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to figure out the best approach for the following situation.  I have several java source files that are using JNI to talk to some C source that all reside on a Linux machine.  The Java portion builds and runs (via JUnit) perfectly on the Linux machine.  The Java classes depend on several Linux (.so) libraries. I would like to run the Eclipse IDE debugger on my local machine (Mac OS X) but use the remote source.  Any suggestions on how to set this up or a different approach?  I've run into several problem trying to compile the remote libraries locally.

Current Setup:
-Eclipse Java project with one class, Test.class (see below).
-Test.class has one dependency sample.jar, this is added as a library in the build path and then I have the mounted linux path to the libSample.so file added for the sample.jar as a native library location.  When I run Test.class I get a

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        System.loadLibrary("Sample");
    }

}
```

**Exception:**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Sample in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you mount the Linux partitions in your Mac and then use an environment variable to "locate" the mnt. Then in Eclipse use that env variable within your project settings for the so libs. I don't know if it works, but it's a possibility.

I don't see doing this unless you can mount the partition locally.
Or build an Eclipse "Remote Debug Plugin"

Comment: thanks for the response, I added some more details to my eclipse setup in my initial question.  Any ideas?

Comment: @c12 provided you are calling the lib with the correct spelling I would suspect the compiler is not wanting to link across a mnt partition. I thought that might be the case, and I am not familiar enough with the Mac fs your on to recommend changing anything in your environment. I will see if I can replicate something this weekend. I am at work right now.